# Better way to write the sum of multiple terms with cross-correlation

Tags: summation

how can I write this expression using summation?

$y^2=x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_1x_3 + 2x_1x_4 + 2x_2x_3 + 2x_2x_4 + 2x_3x_4$

Comment: What do you mean by cross-correlation?

Comment: I don't know how to call the terms $2x_i x_j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider: $$y^2=\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 4}2x_ix_j=\left(\sum_{i=1}^4x_i\right)^2.$$

Comment: Why not $$y^2= \left( \sum_{i=1}^4x_i \right)^2$$ ? Or even $$y= \sum_{i=1}^4x_i$$ ;)

Comment: Edited. Thanks for that haha.

Comment: Since I want to highlight also the terms $2x_i x_j$ the first expression is what I need.
I think it can be also written as $\sum_{\substack{ i,j=1 \\ i\neq j}}^4 x_i^2 +2x_i x_j$